# Mostrar imagenes de una tabla de una base de datos dependiendo del id de otra tabla php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Hola buenas quisiera saber si hay alguna forma mas sencilla de hacer este procedimiento: he creado una página relacionada a 2 bases de datos, en una de ellas esta la información sobre los productos y en la otra se encuentran imágenes, como puedo hacer que al momento de crear un nuevo dato en ambas bases se relacionen todos esos nuevos datos de imágenes instantáneamente a ese nuevo dato de producto. La idea es que al momento de registrar un productos se puedan registrar multiples imágenes y estas mismas se asocien al producto.
Logre hacerlo de la siguiente forma pero siento que no es una forma limpia de hacerlo, tengo un index en el que se encuentran todos los registros en una tabla como primera información y al darle click al numero del id lleva a la pagina correspondiente del producto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo siguiente que se puede apreciar es la sección para crear nuevos registros/productos, en esa misma se carga únicamente el nombre y la cantidad de imágenes que queramos.
Al ingresar a un producto presionando su id se muestra lo siguiente (en este ejemplo presione en el id 25 Mozart):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Finalmente adjunto el código que utilice en cada sección,
En el index (donde se visualizaban y registraban datos):

```
<?php 

require 'config/database.php'; 

$sentenciaSQL = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM producto");
$sentenciaSQL->execute();

$productos=$sentenciaSQL->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$txtID = (isset($_POST['producto']['id'])) ? $_POST['producto']['id'] : "";
$txtNombre = (isset($_POST['producto']['nombre'])) ? $_POST['producto']['nombre'] : "";

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST"){

    if($txtNombre !== ""){
        $sentenciaSQL = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO producto (nombre) VALUES (:nombre);");
        $sentenciaSQL->bindParam(':nombre',$txtNombre);
        $sentenciaSQL->execute();
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['subir'])){
    foreach ($_FILES['imagenes']['tmp_name'] as $key => $value) {

        $random = rand(9999, 999999);
        $ruta = "imagenes/" . $random . ".jpg";

        if(file_exists($_FILES['imagenes']['tmp_name'][$key])){
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagenes']['tmp_name'][$key], $ruta)){
                echo "La imagen se subio<br>";

                $sentenciaSQL = $conexion->query("INSERT INTO imagenes (url, producto) VALUES ('". $ruta ."', '$txtNombre')");
            }
        }
    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach($productos as $producto): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><a href='producto.php?id=<?php echo $producto["id"] ?>'><?php echo $producto['id'];?></a></td>
                <td><a href=""><?php echo $producto['nombre'];?></a></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="txtID">ID:</label>
        <input type="text" required readonly value="<?php echo $txtID;?>" name="producto[id]" id="txtID" placeholder="ID"><br><br>

        <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
        <input type="text" id="nombre" name="producto[nombre]" placeholder="Nombre del producto"><br><br>

        <input type="file" name="imagenes[]" multiple> <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="subir" value="Enviar">
    </form>

    
</body>
</html>
```

Y el archivo php de productos que se redirige al hacer click en cada producto y depende del id del mismo:

```
<?php 

require 'config/database.php'; 

$id = $_GET['id'];

$sentenciaSQL = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM producto " . " WHERE id = ${id}");
$sentenciaSQL->execute();
$producto = $sentenciaSQL->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$txtNombre = $producto['nombre'];

$sentenciaSQL2 = $conexion->prepare(" SELECT * FROM imagenes " . " WHERE producto = '${txtNombre}' ");
$sentenciaSQL2->execute();
$imagenes = $sentenciaSQL2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><?php echo $producto['nombre']; ?></h1>

    <?php foreach($imagenes as $img){ ?>
        
        <img src="<?php echo $img['url']?>" alt="" width="300px">

    <?php } ?> 
</body>
</html>
```

Obvie colocar el php con la conexion a la base de datos pero coloco fotos de como se visualizan las mismas por si es de ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veamos si podemos ayudarte un poco sin confundirte tanto, ya que se ve que estás iniciando. Lo que debes hacer es manejar los IDs de los elementos, así cuando quieras ver las imágenes de un producto cada imagen hará referencia a un ID de producto y no a un nombre como está ahora mismo, la idea es la misma, pero la forma más óptima es con los IDs.

Cuando insertes un nuevo producto en la tabla de productos recupera el ID del producto insertado

```
if($txtNombre !== ""){
    $sentenciaSQL = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO producto (nombre) VALUES (:nombre);");
    $sentenciaSQL->bindParam(':nombre',$txtNombre);
    $sentenciaSQL->execute();
    $lastID = $conexion->lastInsertId(); /* Este es el ultimo ID insertado*/
}
```

Luego en la tabla imágenes colocas ese ID en lugar del nombre.

```
$sentenciaSQL = $conexion->query("INSERT INTO imagenes (url, producto) VALUES ('$ruta', '$lastID')");
```

Y recuperas todo con el ID del producto seleccionado haciendo una unión (join) de ambas tablas. Recomiendo leer sobre los MySQL Join.

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];

$sentenciaSQL = $conexion->prepare("SELECT P.nombre,I.url AS imagen FROM producto P INNER JOIN imagenes I ON P.id = I.producto WHERE P.id = ${id}");
$sentenciaSQL->execute();
$producto = $sentenciaSQL->fetchAll();
$nombre = $producto[0]['nombre'];

/*
Para ver la estructura del array resultante
echo "<pre>";
    print_r($producto);
echo "</pre>";*/

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><?php echo $nombre; ?></h1>

    <?php foreach ($producto as $imagen){ ?>

        <img src="<?php echo $imagen[1]?>" alt="" width="300px">

    <?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Hay muchas cosas más por mejorar en el código, pero creo que la respuesta a tu pregunta está resuelta o por lo menos más clara...

Comment: Hola buenas! Fue de mucha ayuda, lo único que no entendí esta línea: $sentenciaSQL = $conexion->prepare("SELECT P.nombre,I.url AS imagen FROM producto P INNER JOIN imagenes I ON P.id = I.producto WHERE P.id = ${id}");
$sentenciaSQL->execute(); , asumo que deberé informarme con lo del join que mencionaste

Comment: Exacto, ahí hago los [MySQL  Joins](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/joins.php). Recuerde marcar como resuelta su pregunta por favor.